# LIKE in SQL command not working as expected?

Tags: sql

That is my database table

```
--------------------------------
| Product name |    category   |
| Item 1       |   14*#*2*#*1  | 
| Item 2       |   1*#*5*#*14  | 
| Item 3       |   2*#*21*#*5  |
| Item 4       |   5*#*51*#*25 | 
| Item 5       | 100*#*212*#*25| 
| Item 6       | 212*#*55*#*651|
---------------------------------
```

When we run my SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE category LIKE '%1%'
```

It gives the following output:

```
--------------------------------
| Product name | category      |
| Item 1       | 14*#*2*#*1    | 
| Item 2       | 1*#*5*#*14    |
| Item 3       | 2*#*21*#*5    |
| Item 4       | 5*#*51*#*25   |
| Item 5       |100*#*212*#*25 |
| Item 6       |212*#*55*#*651 |
--------------------------------
```

But I want the following result:

```
-------------------------------
| Product name  |   category  |
| Item 1        | 14*#*2*#*1  |
| Item 2        | 1*#*5*#*14  |
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Don't store data like that, it will only cause you lots of trouble... One category per row is the SQL way!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 3):

This is a horrible data structure and you should fix it -- if you can.  SQL has a great way to store lists of things.  It is called a *table*, not a column.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really, really, really, really bad decisions.  If that is the case, you can use `like` like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
WHERE '*#*' || p.category || '*#*' LIKE '%*#*1*#*%';
```

Note that `||` is the ANSI/ISO standard for string concatenation.  Not all databases support this method; yours may have an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   product 
WHERE  category LIKE '1*#*%'
    or category LIKE '%*#*1*#*%'
    or category LIKE '%*#*1%'
```

But do not store data like this, store one category per row. Queries will perform better, and makes everything easier.

Answer (score 1):

We can use 'LIKE' keyword like this

SELECT * FROM product WHERE category ='1' or (category LIKE '%1,%' and category LIKE '%,1%') or category LIKE '%,1' or a.category LIKE '1,%'

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get the 2 records you can use this.

`SELECT * FROM product WHERE category LIKE '%1%' limit 2`

Comment: That doesn't filter out the unwanted records.